# inconsistent behavior of drawn path on zoom in Android

Tags: android

i am working on image editing application and stuck here.

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    // int width=this.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    // int height=this.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
    // float sw=((float)getBitmapRect().width())/width;
    // float sh=((float)getBitmapRect().height())/height;
    matrix = new Matrix();
    // matrix.postScale(sw, sh);

    canvas.setMatrix(getDisplayMatrix());
    canvas.concat(matrix);
    canvas.save();
    if (MainActivity.checkBtnOn == MainActivity.BSS_ONE) {
        for (Pair<Path, Float> p : foregroundPaths) {
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(p.second);
            canvas.drawPath(p.first, mPaint);
         }

    } else if (MainActivity.checkBtnOn == MainActivity.BSS_TWO) {
        for (Pair<Path, Float> p : foregroundPaths) {
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(p.second);
            canvas.drawPath(p.first, mPaint);
        }
    } else {   
        for (Pair<Path, Float> p : foregroundPaths) {
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(p.second);
            canvas.drawPath(p.first, mPaint);
        }
    }

    // matrix.postScale(getScale(), getScale());
    rect = canvas.getClipBounds();
    displayRectF = new RectF(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);
    // rect =drawable.getBounds();


    canvas.restore();

}
```

[without zoom image](http://postimg.org/image/sqr6hfo8p/)

[with zoom image](http://postimg.org/image/4t46u2a8x/)

My question is "What, i am doing wrong that lead me to inconsistent behavior of drawn path." means changes of its location on zoom (For Zoom i am using sephiroth library). I have attached two image link. first image is fit-to-screen and second zoom.

Please help me or any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem solved 
  i have just removed

```
    canvas.setMatrix(getDisplayMatrix()); //removed

    canvas.concat(getDisplayMatrix());  //add
```